# try to get a list of ips attached to the NIC

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-vm

I am trying to get a list of Ip's Attached to a NIC.
Trying to use

`Get-NetIPAddress`. Not getting the list . I have one primary and Multiple secondary ips to a nic.Trying a way to get it all.
[image]

Comment: `Get-NetIPConfiguration` ? what does that give you?

Comment: That looks like Azure, is this an Azure VM?

Comment: yes thats a nic associated to an azure vm

Comment: I am running it though the vm but wanted to know it gives the primary address what about the rest?

Comment: Hi, how's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all private IP addresses of a VM, try the PS command below:

```
$vm = get-azvm -VMName <vm name> -ResourceGroupName <resource Group name>
#get network interface information of vm
$nicRes = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id
#get network interface object 
$nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -name $nicRes.name -ResourceGroupName $nicRes.ResourceGroupName
#read ip configs of this network interface
foreach($ipConfig in $nic.IpConfigurations){
    $ipConfig.PrivateIpAddress
}
```

My IP configs of NIC:
[image]

Result:
[image]